# Failing to connect to pervasive database in Ruby on Rails using odbc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, odbc, pervasive-sql

I have installed Pervasive V10 server x86 and odbc gem. Whenever i make a request to fetch data from the database, I get the following error "IM003 (160) Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Pervasive ODBC Client Interface, C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll)"

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using the 32 bit version of Ruby on Rails?  Which exact version did you install?  Also, what version of the Ruby-ODBC gem are you using?  Is your Ruby installed on the same machine as the Pervasive server or are you running it from the client?  If it's the client, what version of the Pervasive client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The two main causes of the 1114 error are:

- The path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin) to the driver (w3odbcci.dll) is not in the system path.
- You're using the wrong bitness. Is your Ruby on Rails 32 bit or 64 bit?  You'll need to use the same bit driver as the Ruby on Rails enviroment.  If it's 64 bit, you'll need a 64 bit driver.

Comment: I have checked the value of the path variable in the Environment Variables and found that the path is listed there and also check to make sure the bitness matches between my ruby application and the odbc driver but still the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Guess better late than never...for me what solved the issue was set the following environment variable:

```
set RUBY_DLL_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\

@REM Start the app
bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

For completeness the setup I have is as follows:

- Windows 2012 r2
- Ruby 2.7.1 32-bit
- `gem "rails", "6.1.7"`
- `gem 'odbc_adapter', git: 'https://github.com/patterninc/odbc_adapter.git', branch: "master"`
- database.yml (I wanted it to be readonly so that is why openmode is 1 here):

```
development:
  adapter: odbc
  conn_str: "driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};DBQ=MyDB;ServerName=localhost.1583;TransportHint=TCP:SPX;OPENMODE=1;"
```

Some other errors I ran into included:

- `IM002 (0) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.`

  - This was solved by switching from a 64 bit ruby install to a 32 bit ruby install as the ODBC driver for pervasive is 32-bits on this system
- `` odbc.o:odbc.c:(.text+0xc378): undefined reference to `rb_tainted_str_new2' ``

  - Various make errors for the odbc gems I tried went away when I downgraded the Ruby version from 3.2 to 2.7
- `` che/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/bind_visitor (LoadError) ``

  - to get around this one, I was pleasantly surprised to find that the folks at instacart had updated the odbc_adapter gem to work with the updated activerecord modules, however, I did run into another issue:
- `initialize: wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 2..5) ArgumentError)`

  - [patterninc](https://github.com/patterninc/odbc_adapter.git) fork then finally gave me the fork that eventually was able to look up records and return without crashing

I am now able to get queries through to Pervasive, I have yet to explore how well this work though.

Comment: I've updated my entry after realizing that the instacart version was failing to receive the resultant set from the database (probably some incompatibility...what ended up helping is the patterminc fork which finally gave me an object I can use). I still have issues with any queries that use the LIMIT keyword but at least I can work around that with other query types for the time being.

Comment: Yes, and another that sent me off on a wild goose chase is adding double quotes around the path for RUBY_DLL_PATH