# How can I connect to pervasive database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, odbc, pervasive

I have installed Pervasive V10 server x86 and odbc gem. Whenever I make a request to fetch data from the database, I get the following error "IM003 (160) Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Pervasive ODBC Client Interface, C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll)"

I tried installing Pervasive v10 x64 but still it did not work

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263662/failing-to-connect-to-pervasive-database-in-ruby-on-rails-using-odbc

Comment: @engineersmnky yes sir, sure. pretty much the same. my colleague created that one and I didn't know he already did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be running on 32 bit ruby when using x86 pervasive, I used to scratch my head a lot over this exact issue